# One-Sided Hypothesis Test with Categorical Covariate in R, Iris Data Set

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, dataset

I'm currently working with the famous Iris data set in R. I want to test whether the difference in sepal width between setosa and the other plant species is positive, i.e whether setosa has a larger pedal width than each of the other two species.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? I suppose there should be some way to carry out this test in Anova or similar, but thus far I only know how to test whether the Species covariate is significant over all.

Comment: What exactly are your null and alternative hypotheses?

Comment: $H_0$: All species have the same pedal with. VS $H_1$: The difference in pedal width between setosa and versicolor is positive, and the difference in pedal width between setosa and virginica is positive (setosa has a larger pedal with than each of the two other species).

Answer (score 0):

If you believe the three groups to have about the same variance, then this sounds exactly like ANOVA with one-sided post-hoc tests. The special sauce of this is that you use the variance calculated from all three groups, rather than the variance from the pairs of groups being compared, to estimate the common variance shared by the three groups.